# US/Irish Citizen Working for a US company while living in UK--Worth it?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, dual-status

First off, i'm sorry if this has already been asked. I've made the decision to move to London with a friend and I need some guidance. I've been interviewing with a few really good companies in London and things seem to be going well. I recently told my old employer (who i've been freelancing with while traveling) that i'm making the move and i'm going to be looking for new opportunities. She surprised me and asked if I would be interested in working for her company full time while I live in the UK.

She would provide a co-working space and a nice salary. As this US job would pay more than any UK based job I'm looking at, i'm giving it some consideration. My biggest hesitation would be the taxes involved. Since i'm an Irish citizen (with a right to work in the UK) and a US citizen, if I work for this US company while living in the UK, how would taxes work? Who would I pay taxes to? I know I have to file US regardless, but i'm just confused about the entire situation as I assume i'd be considered a self employee since everyone else is back in the US. Im also aware of the tax treaty between the US/UK, i'm just not sure where i'd fall here. Is it worth it to pursue this opportunity, or should I focus on the UK opportunities. Any information would be super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: (1) If you're a US citizen (and don't renounce) you are subject to US tax law full stop -- even if you are a dual citizen _and_ live elsewhere _and_ work elsewhere. In the latter case your US tax can be low or zero, but you must still file -- and if you have _accounts_ in another country, as you likely will need to, and they are over thresholds, you must report them every year on both FBAR and FATCA/8838 or face harsh penalties -- see numerous existing Qs on both. (2) A person working alone or remotely or both _can_ be an employee -- but in a foreign country it's a good deal less hassle ...

Comment: ... for the company if you're a contractor, although somewhat more hassle for you. Although if they provide workspace, and if they pay you a predetermined amount regardless of work done/assigned, that makes it harder to categorize as independent. (3) What you should do is mostly opinion-based and thus against policy for stackexchange,